# how to create pdf file which contains marathi font using itext?

Tags: java, fonts, itext

I have to create report using itext but the language should be hindi or marathi.
Is it possible to make pdf file which contains marathi font like mangal,shruti,shree-dev...etc if yes plz reply me
Thank you!

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775008/embed-font-into-pdf-file-by-using-itext

Comment: Good point, particularly the answer mentioning encodings.  However, if any of these languages require *Shaping*, then all best are off.  iText only supports Arabic shaping.

Comment: Did you try adding a font programattically ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a marathi font in itext pdf is :

```
BaseFont kruti_Dev = BaseFont.createFont("c:/WINDOWS/Font/Kruti_Dev_010.ttf"
                       ,BaseFont.CP1252,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(kruti_Dev, 12, Font.NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Aspose PDF Generator. Make request and response to utf-8.

Comment: Both the question title and the tags show that a solution using itext is sought. Do you want to imply that *Aspose PDF Generator* is based on itext?