# How do you reliably render Khmer (Indic) fonts on the web (and in PDFs)?

Tags: internationalization, fonts, pdf-generation, google-webfonts, indic

I've been having a world of trouble getting Khmer fonts (an Indic script of Cambodia) to render reliably on the web across platforms (Mac, Windows, Linux).

Google web fonts recently added [Khmer](http://www.google.com/webfonts?subset=khmer), which seems like the best bet. However, I have not been successful getting Khmer fonts to work on any Mac or Linux system. I can get them to work on Windows by installing the Khmer Unicode installer from [http://khmeros.info](http://www.khmeros.info/drupal612/) but not by just including Google's font in an HTML file.

For example, see [this screenshot](http://cl.ly/2l1C142U100x091J0l29) of the Google web fonts page on a fresh Windows installation. You can see that the default Windows Khmer font (uuuuugly!) is being used instead of Danh's pretty fonts.

I have another test file here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/634/khmer_test.html. For the first test, you should see [something like this](http://cl.ly/0v3y2w2u2m0j2d123i1l) for both the web font and the default system font (assuming you have Hanuman installed). I have yet to find a system where both examples work reliably.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My primary goal is to get this working on a website; a secondary goal is to get Khmer (and other Indic fonts) working in a PDF generator like [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) (although I am aware iText itself does not support Indic fonts -- I'm hoping something similar does).

Comment: PDFs: (assuming you have rights to) you can [embed a subset of the font into the PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775008/embed-font-into-pdf-file-by-using-itext). Otherwise I'm not 100% clear what you're asking: you're saying the Google web font doesn't work at all for you on any system? I suspect that's down to the browsers - does seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Every Cambodian Windows users are always delete the font name called: KhmerMool and Khmer Kampot. Then they change the default Khmer font in regedit too. You can check at http://thelifeandwork.blogspot.com/2010/01/changing-default-khmer-font-in-windows.html . I'm not sure about Khmer font and other Indic font in PDF. I always have problem when i copy Khmer unicode from PDF to put in OpenOffice or Office Word or LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1):

Khmer Unicode displays on the web, it will always solve now by Google Webfont, please refer to that.

And if you want to have Khmer display in PDF by converting using iText, you can see following post:

- [Khmer Unicode in iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427555/khmer-unicode-in-itext)
- http://ask.osify.com/qa/287

They are currently not yet support the display yet.

But, just today I can get it works by modifying the source code of iText (5.5.4-SNAPSHOT) as I just stated in my post: http://ask.osify.com/qa/613, not yet be able to publish since it's just start in testing around.

Updated 13/01/2016

- I have added the source code sample for the rendering: http://ask.osify.com/qa/613
- The rendering customization with iText for Khmer Unicode added in github: https://github.com/Seuksa/iTextKhmer